# Getting this error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, maps

Am new to **Android One** facing this error after adding **Linear Layout** with **Fragment** in Main Layout. Before it working fine with **Fragment** am using 5.5" device to test app.

```
07-22 19:48:01.775  28504-28504/com.milkywaygalaxy.mymaps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.milkywaygalaxy.mymaps, PID: 28504
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.milkywaygalaxy.mymaps/com.milkywaygalaxy.mymaps.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my new Linear Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@string/verical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@string/horizondal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@string/horizondal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@string/verical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/location"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"/>
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main activity java code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final double SEATTLE_LAT = 47.60621,
SEATTLE_LNG =-122.33207, 
SYDNEY_LAT = -33.867487,
SYDNEY_LNG = 151.20699, 
NEWYORK_LAT = 40.714353, 
NEWYORK_LNG = -74.005973;
private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;
private static final String LOGTAG = "Maps";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (initMap()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG, DEFAULTZOOM);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

While running this app on device on developer mode it showing **Unfortunately app has stopped**. Kindly tell me any suggestions or solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from the exception you should RelativeLayout to optimize your for performance and what does your Activity extend?

Comment: is that the entire stacktrace

Comment: Yeah.. Check I updated question... This code is working fine in XML while using this **fragment** Now i added Linear Layout to XML.. after that only am facing this error...

Comment: is that the entire stacktrace, Do you see anything related to the exception other than the one you posted

Comment: No i copied 1st few lines only coz its much big so... wait i will update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84047/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-sri-hari).